# How do I define a default page for an Apache httpd VirtualHost?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to setup an Apache HTTPD virtual host which will forward to a specific URL.

For example, if someone goes to:

```
https://myhost.mydomain.com/
```

I'd like to forward him to:

```
https://myhost.mydomain.com/ords/f?p=2000
```

I've *almost* got this working, I think...?

I have the following in my VirtualHost definition:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!=/ords/f?p=$appno"
RewriteRule    "/"  "/ords/f?p=$appno" [PT,END]
```

Now, when I do this, I get the (correctly re-written) URL in my browser's URL bar, but in the window, I see:

```
This page isn’t working
myhost.mydomain.com redirected you too many times.
```

Now, I thought the purpose of the 'END' flag was to stop these redirect loops?  (I also tried the 'L' flag with the same result.)

Can someone offer me a clue here?

My Apache skills are novice level, at best.  This has to be a simple task...I'm just not seeing it.

AdvThanksance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm happy to report that I seem to have figured this out, though it was through grasping at straws, rather than a solid understanding of rewrite rules.

All I did was, I changed:

```
RewriteRule    "/"  "/ords/f?p=$appno" [PT,END]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule    "^/$"  "/ords/f?p=$appno" [PT,END]
```

and it works exactly as expected.

I'm not really sure of the difference between "/" and "^/$", but it seems to make all the difference in the world.

If someone could offer an explanation, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!